# Extending integer list to 1-out-of-n binary list

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

Given maximum a list `l` with size `r` of integers with `N` bits, how to do I create a list `binaryL` with size `r*N` where the values reflect the positive bits of `l`?

Example, for `N=2` bits:

`l = [1, 0, 3] --> [01, 00, 11] (in bits)`

becomes

`binaryL = [0, 0, 1,  1, 0, 1]`

where each group of `r` integers equals each bit. In other words, the first `0, 0, 1` is the first bit of `l`, and the final `1, 0, 1` is the last bit of `l`.

Another option is to just obtain the bits in their order, where

`binaryL = [0, 1,  0, 0,  1, 1]`

In this case, each value is converted to its bits.

---

For those wondering about performance,

```
import random
from itertools import chain
import time

N=8
l=[random.randrange(1,2**N,1) for _ in range (10000000)]
r=len(l)

a = time.clock()
res1 = []
for i in l:
    res1 += [int(b) for b in "{0:b}".format(i).rjust(N, '0')]

b = time.clock()
res2 = list(map(int, chain.from_iterable(bin(i)[2:].zfill(N) for i in l)))

c = time.clock()
res3 = list(map(int, ''.join(bin(i)[2:].zfill(N) for i in l)))

d = time.clock()
res4 = [0] * N * r      
for ind, binary in enumerate(map(bin, l)):
    for ind_bit, bit in enumerate(binary[2:].zfill(N)):
        res4[r * ind_bit + ind] = int(bit)

e = time.clock()
res5 = list(map(int, chain.from_iterable(zip(*[bin(i)[2:].zfill(N) for i in l]))))

f = time.clock()

# res1, res2 and res3 are show bits by value. res4 and res5 shows bits by index
print(res1==res2)
print(res2==res3)

print(res4==res5)

print(b-a)
print(c-b)
print(d-c)
print(e-d)
print(f-e)
```

prints for 1000 values:

```
True
True
True
0.003963000000000001  # neverwalkaloner
0.0025400000000000006 # Psidom1
0.0023320000000000007 # Psidom2
0.004358000000000001  # Rockybilly
0.0021629999999999983 # Psidom3
```

and for 10.000.000 values

```
True
True
True
36.333539           # neverwalkaloner
25.674224000000002  # Psidom1
24.49611499999999   # Psidom2
47.370771000000005  # Rockybilly
66.25204            # Psidom3
```

Comment: Why `[01, 00, 11]` becomes `[0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1]` and not `[0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1]`?

Comment: Edited for clarity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `bin` to convert integer to binary representation, and pad the result to specified length with `zfill()`, flatten the list with `chain` and convert the string to int with `map`:

```
from itertools import chain

l = [1, 0, 3]
N = max(l).bit_length()           # as commented by @Jon, use this to determine the maximum 
                                  # bit length

list(map(int, chain.from_iterable(bin(i)[2:].zfill(N) for i in l)))

# [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1]
```

Without using `chain`, another option could be:

```
list(map(int, ''.join(bin(i)[2:].zfill(N) for i in l)))
# [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1]
```

A transposed version:

```
list(map(int, chain.from_iterable(zip(*[bin(i)[2:].zfill(N) for i in l]))))
# [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1]
```

Comment: Is this faster than neverwalkaloner's answer? Should I run performance tests to check this out or is there some obvious advantage to going with `list`, `map`, `chain`, etc?

Comment: Both `map` and `chain` are generators, I reckon the performance shouldn't be bad.

Comment: Best performance and for both versions of the problem. Nicely done

Answer (score 1):

Hope this is what you need:

```
l=[3,4,5,6,7,8]
binaryL = []
for i in l:
    binaryL += [int(b) for b in "{0:b}".format(i).rjust(4, '0')]
```

Comment: I can work with that, but how do I make each value have the same size? `3` only gives me 2 digits, but `8` gives me 4. How would I get 4 digits (or `N` digits) for each value?

Comment: BlueMoon93 you can use rjust() method to append string with leading zeroes: res+=[int(b) for b in "{0:b}".format(i).rjust(4, '0')]

Answer (score 1):

For a more obvious solution that is easier to examine, regular for loops can be used. I make no promises for the performance. (It seems fast.)

```
n = 2 # Max method can be used to find this. As expressed in other answers.
r = 3
l = [1, 0, 3]
new_list = [0] * n * r  # list is prefilled.
                        # Construction similar to C type programming.

for ind, binary in enumerate(map(bin, l)):
    for ind_bit, bit in enumerate(binary[2:].zfill(n)):
        new_list[r * ind_bit + ind] = bit

print new_list
```

Please note that, I wrote this on Python 2, please make the small alterations to work with Python 3.

**Edit:** This find the first `binaryL` in your question not the one you added later, which is easier because simple appending is required.

Comment: Best performing for the original problem. Gj